# XSLTForms / XForms - Namespaces in instance data?

Tags: xml, sparql, dbpedia, xforms, xsltforms

What am I doing wrong here - my XForms data source is a [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) result - and I can get at it using the following XPATH:

```
<bind id="bnd_results"  nodeset="instance('sparql')/*/*/*"/>
```

But I can't seem to get this to work without using the '*' wildcards.
It appears to related to the namespace of instance data.

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'); 
    if (isset($_GET['debug'])) { $debug="yes"; } else { $debug="no"; }
?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options debug="<?=$debug?>"?>
<?php
    $sparqlep="https://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=";
    $sparql=<<<SPARQL
SELECT DISTINCT(?linkedPerson) WHERE {
?s rdfs:label           'World Wide Web Consortium'@en;
        foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipage.
?linkedPerson rdf:type              dbo:Person,
                                    foaf:Person;
              foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?linkedwikipage. 
{ ?s ^dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?linkedPerson.} UNION { ?s dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?linkedPerson. }}
LIMIT 100
SPARQL;
    $url=$sparqlep . rawurlencode($sparql);
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:sparql="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rf1/result2.xsd">
<head>
<model xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
    <instance id="sparql" src="<?=$url?>"/>  
    <instance id="default">
         <data xmlns="">
            <selected/>
         </data>
    </instance>
         <bind id="bnd_results"  nodeset="instance('sparql')/*/*/*"/>
    <bind id="bnd_sel"  nodeset="instance('default')/selected"/>
</model>
</head>
<body>
    <details>
        <summary>SPARQL query</summary>
        <code> <?=$sparql?> </code>
    </details>

    <group xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
        <label>Selected:</label>
        <output bind="bnd_sel"/>
        <select1  appearance="full" bind="bnd_sel">
            <itemset bind="bnd_results">
                <label ref="."/>
                <value ref="."/>
            </itemset>
        </select1>
    </group>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is an extension for XPath 1.0, XSLTForms allows to specify any prefix with "*" such as in "*:myelement".

It is also possible to declare a prefix within the form so it can be used in XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks - and my mistake was I forgot to miss out the 'root' element in my bind.

Answer (score 0):

The following alteration works (missing out the initial '/sparql' in the xpath - and start just with 'results')

```
<bind id="bnd_results"  nodeset="instance('sparql')/sparql:results/sparql:result/sparql:binding[@name='linkedPerson']"/>
```

Here's a working example - also removed PHP from this - this is now just static XHTM + XLSTForms:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:sparql="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rf1/result2.xsd">
<head>
<xf:model>
    <xf:instance id="sparql">
         <data xmlns="">
            <query>prefix dbo: &lt;http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix foaf: &lt;http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
prefix rdfs: &lt;http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?linkedPerson
WHERE {
?s rdfs:label 'World Wide Web Consortium'@en; foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipage.
?linkedPerson a  dbo:Person; foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?linkedwikipage.
{ ?s ^dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?linkedPerson.} UNION { ?s dbo:wikiPageWikiLink ?linkedPerson. }
}
LIMIT 100
            </query>
         </data>
    </xf:instance>

    <xf:instance id="results">
        <sparql:results/>
    </xf:instance>

    <xf:instance id="default">
         <data xmlns="">
            <selected/>
         </data>
    </xf:instance>

    <xf:bind id="bnd_results" nodeset="instance('results')/sparql:results/sparql:result/sparql:binding[@name='linkedPerson']"/>
    <xf:bind id="bnd_sel"     nodeset="instance('default')/selected"/>

    <xf:submission id="run_sparql" method="get" resource="https://dbpedia.org/sparql" ref="instance('sparql')" replace="instance" instance="results">
         <xf:header combine="replace">
            <xf:name>Accept</xf:name>
            <xf:value>application/sparql-results+xml, charset UTF-8</xf:value>
        </xf:header>
    </xf:submission> 

</xf:model>
</head>
<body>
        <xf:textarea ref="instance('sparql')/query" cols="80" rows="10" spellcheck="false">
            <xf:label>SPARQL</xf:label>
        </xf:textarea>
        
        <xf:trigger>
            <xf:label>Submit</xf:label>    
            <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                <xf:send submission="run_sparql"/>  
            </xf:action>
        </xf:trigger>
    <group xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
        <label>Selected:</label>
        <output bind="bnd_sel"/>
        <select1  appearance="full" bind="bnd_sel">
            <itemset bind="bnd_results">
                <label ref="."/>
                <value ref="."/>
            </itemset>
        </select1>
    </group>
</body>
</html>
```